# Convert numeric strings with financial abbreviations to float

Tags: python, string

I was trying to convert strings like:

```
s = '1m'
s = '1.4m'
s = '1k'
s = '1.4k'
```

To what their actual integer is (e.g `'1k'` to `1000`),

And I want a function that I can call with:

```
print(tonum('1m'))
print(tonum('1.4m'))
print(tonum('1.45m'))
print(tonum('1k'))
print(tonum('1.4k'))
print(tonum('1.45k'))
```

Output:

```
1000000
1400000
1450000
1000
1400
1450
```

I tried:

```
def tonum(s):
    if '.' in s:
        return int(s.replace('.', '').replace('m', '00000').replace('k', '00'))
    else:
        return int(s.replace('m', '000000').replace('k', '000'))
```

But it works only for `1.4k` `1k` `1.4m` `1m`, but not `1.45m`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can maintain a dictionary and use that to lookup the right power of 10 to multiply by.

```
def convert_numeric_abbr(s):
    mapping = {'k': 1000, 'm': 1000000, 'b': 1000000000}
    # Do a check first so it doesn't choke on valid floats     
    if s[-1].isalpha():
        return float(s[:-1]) * mapping[s[-1].lower()]

    return float(s)
```

```
convert_numeric_abbr('1m')
# 1000000.0

convert_numeric_abbr('1.4m')
# 1400000.0

convert_numeric_abbr('1k')
# 1000.0

convert_numeric_abbr('1.4k')
# 1400.0
```

Comment: Very nice, just a note that In Python3 we could write also: `'b': 1_000_000_000` (PEP515)

Answer (score 1):

Although [`eval` is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice), you can use this as a proof of concept:

```
def tonum(s):
    return eval(s.replace('k', '*1e3').replace('m', '*1e6'))
```

As a bonus, this will also correctly compute expressions such as:

```
tonum("140k + 1m")
```

Comment: Nice one as well, but gonna go with colds answer as it doesn't have `eval` :P